# Why is my App always shifted to the right in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, xcode-storyboard

I am building a simple iOS app using Storyboards. Currently running Xcode 7.2.1. I have previously built one using .XIB files and never had an issue with layouts on devices.

I have a UIViewController that has a UINavigationBar and Bar Button Item.  When I run the app in the simulator, everything looks shifted to the right and partly off screen. The title should be shown in the centre. I am simulating using iPhone 6 and everything in Simulated Metrics are set to Inferred. Could someone help me understand, am I missing a step?

[image]

[image: View in simulator]

Comment: What about when you run on device?

Comment: Because you don't have any autolayout constraints on your views so they have 600 width which is obviously wider than the device's width

Comment: Thanks. I just found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457239/storyboards-view-is-different-from-simulators-view

Answer (score 0):

The views are shifted because you didn't set the auto layout constraints. To fix this, **add missing constraints**.